Are co-wives halachically related
Are co-wives halachically related? If one of them dies does the other co-wife have to sit shivah for her co-wife?

There are many other ways to measure relatedness besides sitting shiva

They are not on the list of immediate relatives vis-a-vis shiva. Though if one dies, the husband will sit shiva, and the spouse of a mourner is expected to show certain elements of mourning in their presence.

They are Halachically related but only in the context halacha decides. They  would not sit shiva for each other because Shiva is limited for seven relatives and those who Chazal added(YD 374:4) Co wives are not on the list.  If one would die during the lifetime of the husband it is possible that cowife  would need to observe limited rules of Shiva as is the case whenever someone who one would sit Shiva on is sitting Shiva themselves. (see ibid:6)
They are related in other ways. Mesechtas Yevomas is full of  ways this relationship has an halachic impact one on the other
